# Error message when I try to run a virtual computer

Tags: virtualbox

I'm kind of new to virtual computers. I am getting this error message when I try to run a virtual system:

```
[Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).


Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
]
```

[image]

Comment: You may wish to take a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33304393/3395469).

Answer (score 14):

The error message is very clear in this case. Your CPU virtualization options are turned off in the BIOS.

You need to reboot in to the BIOS and Enable VT-x.

According to the manual:
http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06002345

> "Turn on or restart the computer, quickly press esc, and then press
>   f10."

Under the **System Configuration** Tab. Check if there is **Virtualization Technology** listed.

**Enable** it.

Comment: MB is 15-ce019dx and I run windows 10

Comment: Please do not only respond in the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.

Comment: On AMD-Ryzen it is called SVM Mode